# draw a picture from left button side in android(Canvas)

Tags: android, canvas, anchor, image

i want to draw a picture from left button side ,  in J2me we have anchor parameter like Graphic.LEFT|Graphic.Button in draw method how can i do this in android ?
thanks

Comment: do you want that for drawing on a canvas or for layouts - the equivalent to the J2ME term _anchors_ in android is the term _gravity_

Comment: yes a want to draw on a canvas

Answer (score 2):

You would use the android:drawableLeft property.

```
<Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```